# Core Data Crash that redirects to the app delegate persistentStoreCoordinator mathod

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, crashlytics

Hi everyone I am trying to implement core data to a table view from my app, to avoid unwanted internet traffic the problem is that I am new to core data and also at the beginning of the implementation.

So here you have my core data Entity and how it looks:

[image: entity model]

I am using only one Entity, with the model that you can see in the photo and also with NSmanagedObjectSubclass.

What I am doing is:
1. I download an XML from the internet and I save in NSUserDefaults for better persistence, so that if the app is launched for the first time I check if the the NSUserDefaults exists than I download it again in the viewDiaAppear, and if it is for the first time I download the data in viewDidLoad.
2. So creating the data for the first Time and retrieving it in the table view works fine 
3. But when the app launches for the second, It does a series of conditions at witch point it crushes during one of them witch I don't know for sure, so I added CrashLitiscs and these is what I am getting:

[image: crash report in Crashlytics]

but at the line specified I have no array, not only at that line but nothing near that line above or beneath.

These is the code at the line from Crashlytics

```
//check ID
if ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count] != suggestedEntityForGroup.groupName) {
    //replace with new data
    suggestedEntityForGroup.groupID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
    NSError *managedObjError = nil;
    if (![[self appDelegate].managedObjectContext save:&managedObjError]) {
        NSLog(@"Next error ocured:%@ while updating group id at position:%d", managedObjError, count);
    }
}
```

**And here is the entire [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nymdd8hzhr29po2/CoreDataCode.rtf?dl=0) that handles core data DB after the XML is retrieved:**

and here is the console log after the crash:

**CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/laurentiu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F02B530-AB90-4B1B-BBAA-08B3B9C14ECA/data/Containers/Data/Application/668593BE-16B2-419E-ACB9-95FB38A8A90B/Documents/ChannerApp.sqlite options:{
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
        NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    } ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x7fa4d600ce70 {URL=file:///Users/laurentiu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F02B530-AB90-4B1B-BBAA-08B3B9C14ECA/data/Containers/Data/Application/668593BE-16B2-419E-ACB9-95FB38A8A90B/Documents/ChannerApp.sqlite, metadata={
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
            Asd = <6acf157c fdf3a06b 00e10f78 074562df 987e2334 be30294e ae73e5c1 cdc1f9b1>;
            SuggestedChannelsEntity = ;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "D73CCCB1-F3AE-4153-83AE-2D1B6D91E3D9";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    }, reason=Can't find model for source store} with userInfo dictionary {
        URL = "file:///Users/laurentiu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F02B530-AB90-4B1B-BBAA-08B3B9C14ECA/data/Containers/Data/Application/668593BE-16B2-419E-ACB9-95FB38A8A90B/Documents/ChannerApp.sqlite";
        metadata =     {
            NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
            NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
                Asd = <6acf157c fdf3a06b 00e10f78 074562df 987e2334 be30294e ae73e5c1 cdc1f9b1>;
                SuggestedChannelsEntity = ;
            };
            NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
            NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
                ""
            );
            NSStoreType = SQLite;
            NSStoreUUID = "D73CCCB1-F3AE-4153-83AE-2D1B6D91E3D9";
            "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
        };
        reason = "Can't find model for source store";
    }
    2015-04-24 17:45:34.467 ChannerApp[11021:412450] CoreData: annotation: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's current model hashes are {
        SuggestedChannelsEntity = ;
    }
    2015-04-24 17:45:34.468 ChannerApp[11021:412450] Unresolved error Error Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN Code=9999 "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" UserInfo=0x7fa4d3c9e0c0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data., NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa4d600e2c0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)"}, {
        NSLocalizedDescription = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
        NSLocalizedFailureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
        NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)\" UserInfo=0x7fa4d600ce70 {URL=file:///Users/laurentiu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F02B530-AB90-4B1B-BBAA-08B3B9C14ECA/data/Containers/Data/Application/668593BE-16B2-419E-ACB9-95FB38A8A90B/Documents/ChannerApp.sqlite, metadata={\n    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;\n    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {\n        Asd = <6acf157c fdf3a06b 00e10f78 074562df 987e2334 be30294e ae73e5c1 cdc1f9b1>;\n        SuggestedChannelsEntity = ;\n    };\n    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;\n    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (\n        \"\"\n    );\n    NSStoreType = SQLite;\n    NSStoreUUID = \"D73CCCB1-F3AE-4153-83AE-2D1B6D91E3D9\";\n    \"_NSAutoVacuumLevel\" = 2;\n}, reason=Can't find model for source store}";
    }**

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is ````count````?

Comment: are you referring to: ** int count = 0; count < suggestionsResponseDict.count; count++** ? it is a local declared counter

Comment: OK, at the end of you error, it says "Can't find model for source store", that seems like you have a datastore but haven't properly declared your data model.

Comment: @Laur Stefan: It seems like the creation of store coordinator is getting called from multiple threads. When you use appDelegates's managedObjectContext at first time the store coordinator is created. Check the managedObjectContext is accessed in multiple threads. If so, Try synchronising this with @synchronized().

Comment: @ShanmugarajaG and how should I do that? can you provide an example?

Comment: Not only the multi thread calls of same context can be reason. There may be lot of reasons the crash may happen. If the appDelegate's managedObjectContext is used only at second time(means the logic you did for second time) then as error says, the model (xcdatamodel) and the store (ChannerApp.sqlite) is not matched. Once the app is installed in simulator/device and any changes made in the data model(ChannerApp.xcdatamodel) then  delete the app from simulator/device then clean and run again.

Comment: found the problem, and fixed the bug, I will return with a more detail answer, there were some bugs in the logic and also the [self appDelegate].managedObjectContext was some part of this particular charsh